# 64 bit double precision floating point CPU using verilog

Tags: floating-point, verilog

how to convert 64 bit decimal value into the 64 bit binary value??
what is the range of the decimal values of 64 bit????
64 bit decimal values means in floating point...

Comment: "64 bit decimal value" just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @TonyK: well, theoretically you could interpret those 64 bits as 16 decimal digits encoded in BCD.

Comment: Perhaps that what the OP meant. Maybe you can enlighten us, swapna.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your understanding of what floating point values are is rather vague. I recommend reading [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/). Then you'll hopefully understand why your question already contains false assumptions.

Comment: ya i knw dta what i wrote yesterday u could nt understand...but i got i ans. its very simple...can u pls suggest me the free floating point calculator???